Issue Accessing ECS Service with Static IP (NAT Gateway and Load Balancer)
I’m experiencing a problem with an AWS ECS service and need some help.
Scenario:
ECS Service: I have set up an ECS service that is configured with a Load Balancer.
Subnets: I have defined two subnets in the same VPC, each in different Availability Zones. These subnets are used for both the ECS service and the Load Balancer.
Route Tables: Both subnets use the same route table, which routes 0.0.0.0/0 to a NAT Gateway.
Public IP: I am using a NAT Gateway for internet access, and it is associated with an Elastic IP.
Problem:
Auto Assign Public IP: When I enable auto assign public IP, the IP assigned to the ECS tasks is not related to the Elastic IP associated with the NAT Gateway; it is assigned dynamically. This IP is not the static IP I expect.
Auto Assign Public IP Disabled: When I disable auto assign public IP, no IP is assigned to the ECS tasks, and therefore, there is no external access.
Solutions Tried:
The route tables for the subnets are configured correctly and are associated with the NAT Gateway.
The subnets for the ECS service and the Load Balancer are the same.
Question:
How can I ensure that ECS tasks are accessible through the static IP associated with the NAT Gateway?
Why does enabling auto assign public IP not assign an IP related to the NAT Gateway’s Elastic IP, and how can I properly assign this IP?
Additional Information:
ECS Task Definition: My task definition has networkMode set to awsvpc.
NAT Gateway: The NAT Gateway is properly configured and associated with an Elastic IP.
Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!


Auto Assign Public IP: When I enable auto assign public IP, the IP assigned to the ECS tasks is not related to the Elastic IP associated with the NAT Gateway; it is assigned dynamically. This IP is not the static IP I expect.

The ECS tasks, and the NAT Gateway are two completely separate resources with separate IP addresses. You would not want to assign public IP addresses to resources in private subnets. You would either use a NAT Gateway, or you would assign public IP addresses to the ECS tasks, not both at the same time.

Auto Assign Public IP Disabled: When I disable auto assign public IP, no IP is assigned to the ECS tasks, and therefore, there is no external access.

That's what the load balancer is for. However you have also placed the load balancer in your private subnets, so you can't access the load balancer either.

How can I ensure that ECS tasks are accessible through the static IP associated with the NAT Gateway?

You can't. That's not what NAT gateways are for. NAT Gateways are only for allowing private resources to make outbound connections to the Internet. You never send incoming requests directly to a NAT Gateway.

Why does enabling auto assign public IP not assign an IP related to the NAT Gateway’s Elastic IP, and how can I properly assign this IP?

You can't. That's not how IP addresses work. The NAT Gateway has that IP address, you can't also assign that same IP address to other things.
Again, you make no mention at all of your load balancer here other than the fact that you have one. You don't seem to be attempting to use the load balancer at all. The load balancer is the device that accepts incoming requests and forwards those requests to the ECS tasks.

Solution:
Both the NAT Gateway and the load balancer need to be in public subnets (subnets with a route to an Internet Gateway). If you need a static IP address  to send incoming requests to, then you would have to use a Network Load Balancer, and assign an Elastic IP to that.
The ECS tasks would need to be in the private subnets (subnets with a route to a NAT Gateway). You would not enable "assign public IP" to the ECS tasks.
To send any requests to the application, you would send the request to the IP address, or DNS address, of the load balancer.
When your ECS tasks need to make outbound requests, such as to make a call to an external API or something, that outbound request will automatically be routed through the NAT Gateway, and appear to the external resource as if it came from the NAT Gateway's IP address.
